# Jackson ObjectMapper: NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse

Tags: android, json, jackson, noclassdeffounderror

In my Android app, I want to use ObjectMapper of Jackson for convert JSON to String. I use Eclipse. I don't use Maven. Here is my problem:

If I add jackson-databind-2.6.0.jar, jackson-cores-2.6.0.jar, jackson-annotations-2.6.0.jar to folder libs, I get this message:

**Your project contains error(s). Please fix them before running your application.**

If I don't  add them to libs, but add them as external JAR in Java Build Path, I got this message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
```

I cannot find out what happened. Please help me!

Comment: Did you check all check box in `"Java Build Path" ->
                              "Order and Export"` Tab?

Comment: @MrNeo Yes, I did. But it doesn't work

Comment: I got this error before with `ZXing`, and after import or add .jar file into libs folder, clean and rebuild project is very important